# Intermittent IndexOutOfRangeException in ChannelServices.RegisteredChannels

Tags: c#, multithreading, remoting

We've been getting this exception intermittently in our applications:

```
System.IndexOutOfRangeException: Index was outside the bounds of the array.
at System.Runtime.Remoting.Channels.ChannelServices.get_RegisteredChannels()
at ProductCacheServiceClient.getProductCacheServiceProvider(DataServiceConnectionDetails connOptions)
```

Since it's intermittent and we call this quite a lot (in a web app, so can be concurrent) I thought maybe it was a threading issue but I've had a look in [`ChannelServices.get_RegisteredChannels`](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/runtime/remoting/channelservices.cs,296) and although this is interacting with a list of channels, it takes a copy of the reference and both `RegisterChannel` and `UnregisterChannel` appear to have locks, and replaced the list in one go.

We're stumped... If the locks are working as advertised and the MSDN docs are correct (it says static members of this class are threadsafe) then what could cause an IndexOutOfRange inside this property?

**Edit**: I've managed to make a small console app that will intermittently (about 1 in 5 runs in my testing) throw this exception. Im compiling in VS 2015 Update 1 targeting .NET 4.5.2.

```
List<Task> tasks = new List<Task>();

for (var i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
{

    var task = Task.Run(() =>
    {
        var chanProps = new System.Collections.Hashtable();
        chanProps["name"] = "cacheServicesClient" + Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
        chanProps["username"] = "a";
        chanProps["password"] = "b";
        chanProps["domain"] = "c";

        var channelToReturn = new TcpChannel(chanProps, null, null);
        bool registered = false;
        foreach (var channelRegistered in ChannelServices.RegisteredChannels)
        {
            if (channelRegistered.ChannelName == channelToReturn.ChannelName)
            {
                registered = true;
                break;
            }
        }

        if (!registered)
        {
            ChannelServices.RegisterChannel(channelToReturn, true);
        }
    }).ContinueWith(t =>
    {
        if (t.IsFaulted && t.Exception != null)
        {
            t.Exception.Handle(e =>
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
                return true;
            });
        }
    });

    tasks.Add(task);
}

Task.WaitAll(tasks.ToArray());
```

and here's the error when it crashes:

```
System.IndexOutOfRangeException: Index was outside the bounds of the array.
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Channels.ChannelServices.get_RegisteredChannels()
   at ConsoleApplication1.Program.<>c.<Main>b__0_0() in C:\Work\Source\TestApps\ConsoleApplication1\Program.cs:line 28
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute()
Press any key to continue . . .
```

Comment: Looking at sources this could happens if `channel is CrossAppDomainChannel` condition is `false` for all channels. Algorithm expect what it will be one less and allocates array of less than `count` size, which lead to said exception. You can re-implement that method, but do it without that assumption.

Comment: @Danny, thank you for reporting the issue. We have reviewed the related code, looks like we have code to make sure CrossAppDomainChannel is always registered. That is why ChannelServices.get_RegisteredChannels has the assumption of count size won’t be smaller than 1. However, there could be race condition issue as you have run into. In order to do further investigation, can you share a repro with us? If it is not easy to get simple repro, can you share a dump file with us?

Comment: @DannyTuppeny a colleague of mine, Alicia, had sent you an email. Please let me know if you didn't get one.

Answer (score 0):

We've confirmed in our repro that adding locks around this code fixed the problem. We believe the issue occurs when the first thread is inside `ChannelServices.RegisterChannel` and a second thread hits `ChannelServices.RegisteredChannels` at the same time. We believe it only happens on the very first hits to these (when the list is first populated with a `CrossAppDomainChannel`) so possible workarounds include:

1. Registering a single channel (to completion!) before allowing any other threads to try and create channels
2. Put locks around the whole chunk of code

Since our use is low volume, it's probably going to be simpler to just lock around the whole thing. Depending on your code, this may or may not be suitable!